# C# DataGridView, column multiplier format

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am currently trying to set a multiplier for any values that initially gets put into the data grid view.

If I do something similar to below

```
for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(i * 2000, i*3000, i*4000);      
}
```

I would have 2000 in my first row. What I want to do is make it appear as 2 instead without actually modifying the values being placed into the datagridview.

I tried playing around with this but I am not sure what to place into the brackets to get the divided by 1000

```
dataGridView1.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "000."; 
// just playing around with how this behaves
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try DataGridView CellFormatting, described here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z1cc356h.aspx?ppud=4

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender,
    DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 0)
        {
            e.Value = Convert.ToInt32(e.Value.ToString()) * 2000 // apply     formating here
            e.FormattingApplied = true;
        }
        //repeat for additional columns
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

> I would have 2000 in my first row.

NO, it will be `0` since `i` starting with `i = 0`.

> What I want to do is make it appear as 2 instead without actually
>   modifying the values being placed into the datagridview.

I believe you can just divide with 1000 to get that value

```
Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value) / 1000; // produce 2
```